# Statistical analysis for two questionnaires

Tags: python, r, anova

I am working on a research paper and I need to organize the statistical analysis part. I have two questionnaires with the same number of participants (15 cases).
Basically, we asked the participants to play two different games with two different conditions.

- Imagine:
  Game A (under conditions 1 and 2) (questionnaire with 5 questions).
  Game B (under conditions 1 and 2) (questionnaire with 7 questions).
  And we asked them to fill out the questionnaire to estimate the overall satisfaction for each condition.
  I am wondering that whats could be the best statistical method here to analyze the results for each condition. Is (one/two way) ANOVA a good solution?
  If yes is it a good way to do it on Python? (unfortunately, I am not familiar with R and I'm kinda in rush)
  Here is an example of the result of the questionnaires for only one person (1 out of 15).
  [image]

Comment: can you share what you have tried? Otherwise i think it's more of a statistical question rather than programming

Comment: I think the first part of my question is mainly related to statistics. I am not yet do coding, I'm curious if python is a good option rather than R?

Comment: You need to say what you want to compare and using what data.  Compare Conditions 1 and 2? Games A and B? Presumably the comparison will be based on questionnaires with 15 ('cases' or 'questions', or with 5 or 7 questions). As is, it's a jumble of games, conditions, groups and questionnaires. //. What do questionnaires provide? (Number 'correct'? Opinions 1-5? Sores 0-100?) // Can you show a partial table with some results suitably organized? // We wouldn't provide Python or R code. Perhaps with some clue as to the experimental design, someone can recommend a statistical test or procedure.

Comment: first, thank you for your help and your comments. Mainly I want to compare each condition for each game. In other words, I like to know for "Game A" which condition is the preference of the player. and for Game B again which condition is better. So basically I am not comparing these games together. For both questionnaires, each question has to be answered on a five-point Likert scale. I am adding an example image of the dataset sheet also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the revised question.

*For Game A.* The two conditions were scored very
similarly, and you have only 7 scores.

```
a1 = c(4, 3.5, 3, 4, 4.5, 4, 4)
a2 = c(4,   4, 4, 3,   4, 4, 4)
```

A paired Wilcoxon signed rank test finds no
difference between conditions. The P-value
is not exact because of the ties in the data.
Tests from R.

```
wilcox.test(a1, a2, pair=T)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test 
    with continuity correction

data:  a1 and a2
V = 5, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Treating the scores as numerical (even though
I wonder if they may be ordinal categorical choices),
we find no difference (high P-value), again because the scores
are so nearly the same for the two conditions.

```
t.test(a1, a2)$p.val
[1] 1
```

*For Game B.* In all five categories, Condition 2
was preferred. The Wilcoxon signed rank test will not
work because of ties in the differences. However, regarding data as numerical, a paired t test is significant
at the 5% level (P-value $0.012 < 0.05 = 5\%.)$

```
b1 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 4)
b2 = c(5, 4, 5, 5, 4.5)
t.test(b1, b2, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  b1 and b2
t = -4.3333, df = 4, p-value = 0.01232
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.1329335 -0.4670665
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   -1.3
```